# Important values in soap envelope header

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

Can someone explain to me why developers of their web services sometimes store important variables in the message header?

For example:

```
<wsdl:message name="PSIMCmtplPaymentResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:PSIMCmtplPaymentResponse"/>
/wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="PSIMCmtplPaymentResponse_Headers">
<wsdl:part name="code" element="tns:code"/>
<wsdl:part name="message" element="tns:message"/>
<wsdl:part name="result" element="tns:result"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

After the automatic generation of the code (Apache Axis2 wsdl2java), it is not possible to get the value of the variables stored in the header, using the methods provided to me from the generated classes.

Because of this, I have to use different constructions like:

```
SOAPHeader header = service._getServiceClient().getLastOperationContext().
getMessageContext("In").getEnvelope().getHeader().getAttributeValue(
new QName("result"));`
```

Instead of smth like:

```
PSIMCmtplPaymentResponse response = service.cmtplPayment(request);
String paymentResult = response.getResult()
```

In addition to payment requests, some other requests to the web service can also be called at the same time, and I'm afraid that when the method

```
getMessageContext("In")
```

is called, values from an entirely different query may come to me.

I ask this because it is not the first time I encounter such inconveniences. Is this some kind of generally accepted agreement or conventions? Or it's just personal preferences of web service developers?